# pyyaml syntax differences for different .yaml file formats

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am learning about yaml files and using pyyaml to parse through them, and ran into an issue that I am struggling to find a solution to.  Essentially the situation is this: I have two .yaml files in two different formats and while I can access subdirectories in on file, the same syntax does not access the subdirectories in the second file.

Here are two .yaml files:

file1.yaml (source: https://dev.to/developertharun/yaml-tutorial-using-yaml-with-python-pyyaml-443d):

```
---
    username: Shiv
    password: shiv@456
    path:
        - VLC Media Player: /etc/vlc
        - Visual Studio Code: /etc/vscode
        - Google Chrome: /etc/chrome
    softwares:
        s1:
            - VLC Media Player
        s2:
            - Visual Studio Code
            - Google Chrome
            - Git Bash
            - Video Convertor
            - Node Js
```

And here is file2.yaml:

```
681:
    activities:
        copying:
            time: 480
        manufacturing:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 86
                typeID: 38
682:
    activities:
        copying:
            time: 480
        manufacturing:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 133
                typeID: 38
```

The following code opens each .yaml file, prints the entire yaml file contents, and tries to print the first entry, 'username' and '681' respectively

```
import yaml

# A function to read a .yaml file
def read_yaml(filename):
    with open('%s'%filename) as f:
        file = yaml.safe_load(f)
    return file

# read first file, pretty print file contents,
# and print value of 'username' key:
file1 = read_yaml('file1.yaml')
pprint.pprint(file1)
print(file1['username'])

# read second file, pretty print file contents,
# and print value of '681' key:
file2 = read_yaml('file2.yaml')
pprint.pprint(file2)
print(file2['681'])
```

This code fails at the last line and gives a KeyError: '681'

So, as you can see, pyyaml can load the two files above, but there is something going wrong with respect to calling the root dictionaries in file2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `681` (integer rather than string) as the key for the second file?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the format difference, but in simple auto-conversion of the numbers to integer, not string. If you just drop the quotes in the last printing line like this:

```py
print(file2[681])
```

then you will get the expected result, i.e. the dict corresponding to the first section.

Or vice versa, to prevent the auto-conversion, the value should be explicitly quoted as string in the yaml file:

```
'681':
    activities:
...
```

(Perhaps the confusing part was that Python can have integers as dictionary keys - or, in fact, any hashable type, see also [Glossary | Python](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)...?)

Comment: To be fair, the rules for what needs to be quoted in YAML are ridiculously complex; for instance, a small fraction of MAC addresses need to be quoted, exactly one country code ("no" for Norway); some things like ::1 only need to be quoted in some contexts. The quoting rules in YAML are a mess.